# Informelles Wort für "current"

Tags: usage, single-word-request

Nehmen wir an, dass ich einer Freundin den Satz

> I like my current office a lot.

ausdrücken möchte.

> Mein ___ Büro gefällt mir sehr.

Ich habe mir die [Übersetzungen von "current"](https://translate.google.com/#auto/de/current) angeschaut. "Aktuell" ist vielleicht nicht passend, und "gegenwärtig", "derzeitig", und "jetzig" klingen irgendwie alle zu formell. (Oder vielleicht ist "jetzig" nicht so formell?) Was wäre ein gutes Wort?

Comment: Wie Du eigentlich auch wäre ich für "jetzig".

Comment: Solange die Situation noch neu ist, ist eindeutig "mein neues Büro" bevorzugt. (Und viele Situationen werden auch lange nach dem Wechsel noch als "neu" bezeichnet. Faktoid: die älteste von allen Brücken in paris ist der "Pont neuf"...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> derzeitig

ist überhaupt nicht *zu* formell. Ich würde es nicht einmal als formell einstufen, wobei viele wahrscheinlich zu einer Umschreibung mit "jetzt" oder "gerade" greifen würden, wie zB in

> Das Büro, in dem ich jetzt bin, gefällt mir sehr.

Mit

> jetzig

sieht es ähnlich aus (wäre übringens meine Wahl) und "aktuell" ist lediglich ein Lehnwort. Dafür passt  "gegenwärtig" nicht wirklich - es bedeutet, dass etwas jetzt gerade da ist/dessen Wirkung in diesem Moment wahrgenommen werden kann.

Answer (score 1):

Je nach Kontext geht vielleicht noch "aktuell", aber wenn's wirklich kein bisschen gebildet klingen darf - "derzeitig" hat schon Abitur - würde man einen Nebensatz nehmen.

> Ich mag das Büro, wo ich grad arbeite.

Comment: Das klingt für mich nach "grad in diesem Moment, aber in 5 Minuten nicht mehr", während ich die Originalfrage so verstehe, als ob sich das "current office" auf einen längeren Zeitraum bezieht.

Comment: Auch wenn Informelles gefragt war, muss man sich nicht auf das schwäbische Generalrelativpronomen "wo" zurückziehen.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Das ist nicht schwäbisch. Ich hab mit den Schwaben nichts am Hut und sag das auch.

Comment: Natürlich war das von mir polemisch, und hier wird es ja zumindest auf einen Ort bezogen benutzt. Trotzdem würde ich „in dem“ vorziehen.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz In diesem Fall sind *in dem* und *wo* vollkommen gleichwertig.